# How can i send & Receive Push Notification in IBM Mobile First App with GCM or FCM?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Am new to IBM Mobile First Development, What are all thing need for Receive Push Notification in IBM Mobile First App?

Am already done send & receive push notification with GCM in Android(Native App) from Tomcat Server.

1. Is there Any Step by step document for Receive Push Notification and Configure with GCM ?
2. Did i need any extra server to send GCM Push Notification to IBM Mobile First App.
3. Please explain about MobileFirst Server and What it usage.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Google recently changed stuff and moved from GCM to FCM.

Existing applications that already use GCM can continue working with GCM.
New applications must be configured according to FCM.

Note that the FCM configuration detailed in the firebase site is **not required** in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. Instead you need to follow the exact instructions specified in the MobileFirst Foundation documentation for FCM. You can find this documentation here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#google-cloud-messaging--firebase-cloud-messaging

1. Visit the Firebase Console.
2. Create a new project and provide a project name.
3. Click on the Settings “cog wheel” icon and select Project settings.
4. Click the Cloud Messaging tab to generate a Server API Key and a Sender ID. and click Save.

To receive notifications in client applications, follow the client-side documentation: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/android/